# Are there any generic statistical board software?

Tags: statistics

I was thinking about monitoring the evolution of a single value (nope, this is not the SO rep :-p), and I'd like to have some nice histograms about it. My needs are simple:

- daily / weekly / monthly / yearly evolution histograms;
- daily / weekly / monthly / yearly calculation for max, min and average value.

Ideally the product should be scriptable so I can feed it with the result of the script.

Something simple like: set it up, set cron (or, if it has a daemon, even better), set input, enjoy output.

If it does not exist, do you feel like you would be interested in such a tool. Because I could end up coding it eventually.

EDIT :

I am not looking for a lib or a language but an app.

Comment: Yeap, that simple. With ketchup please.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if they are what you are looking for, but I would look at the R statistics packages and the various Python numerical and scientific libraries, like numpy and scipy. They are probably overkill, but they might have graphical components that you can leverage.

Comment: It is, I just want some daemon updating a database with a value and ouputing charts. Not a full stat stack. I don't want to do the calculation myself if I can avoid it.

Comment: Ah. I see. I think I might leave this answer here in case someone stumbles upon this question looking for the things I suggested, if you don't mind.

Comment: Nope, that's what SO is for :-) Anyway, it looks like it's a project that I will end up coding myself. Free time, where are you ?

Answer (score 1):

How about [RRDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/)?

Comment: Sounds cool, but a bit overkill. Anyway, closest to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From a Java program you can create charts with  [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)